# How to disable get last inserted id in CakePHP

Tags: php, postgresql, cakephp, postgresql-8.4

## Question

I'm working with a database with **composite primary key**, and CakePHP doesn't support that.

So, when I save some information, CakePHP try to get the last inserted id, but return some errors (exactly because this table/model not have 'one primary key' but two or more.

So, how can I disable that?

**Note:** I want get the last query executed and all other informoations, just not the last inserted id **action**.

### Tests

I try a lot solutions for modificate CakePHP support to compositve primary key, but, only the modifications on **core** works, and I know this is not a good pratice, so I discarded.

#### Modifications in CakePHP core for work with composite primary keys

*Not a good pratice but, if you need*

*Note.: I try do my best but my code maybe is not the best option for do that, and sorry for the "multiplePrimarykey, and not use compositePrimaryKey"*.

**git diff:** https://gist.github.com/patrickmaciel/7662749

In summary

```
// Add this in your model
public $primaryKey = false;
public $multiplePrimaryKey = array('key_one', 'key_two');

// Done :)
```

## Environment

- CakePHP 2.4.3
- Composer
- PostgreSQL 8.4
- Windows 7 x64
- Sublime Text 2

*Sorry for my english*

Comment: You should post the modifications you're making to the core to get it working. It will help people understand what's working, and how to pull those changes out of the core and into your app itself.

Comment: Let's be blunt: There is no need to ever use compositve primary keys. Its nice, sure. But it's not required to make things work. Why making life difficult and start hacking around when you can just add a simple "id" column as single primary key?

Comment: Let's be blunt: any framework that can't handle anything as simple as a composite key is useless. Why screw up your database when you can just replace the framework? I gave up on Cake after having to make far too many changes back in the v1 days.

Comment: @mark I'm working in a customer database, not mine. I can't modified the tables or primary keys or whatever I want, because has some other apps using this database, so, it's impossible. And, of course, I know composite primary keys is a bad bad pratice. Anyway, thanks so much for the asnwer.

Comment: @joshua.paling I change a lot fields, so, I need some time to get all changes and post here.

Comment: @RichardHuxton I know compositve primary key is useless, because that I never use in my personal projects, but my customer use and I can't change the database. So, is that.

Comment: @joshua.paling modifications in cakephp core https://gist.github.com/patrickmaciel/7662749

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I follow the instructions of [@mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/461173/mark) blog, and I can use my custom `Model.php` and `DboSource.php` without change the original files of CakePHP core.

**Post:** http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/10/31/freshly-baked-cake2-0-tips/

> Using own classes instead of core ones
>
> Let’s say, you want to apply a fix to a core file without overriding the core folder. Or you want to replace a file altogether.
>
> Simply use the same folder structure inside the /Lib folder. For your
>   own “FormAuthenticate”
>   /app/Lib/Controller/Component/Auth/FormAuthenticate.php

### Diff with CakePHP core files

The diff of my code and original cakephp core you found here: https://gist.github.com/patrickmaciel/7662749

### Solution

I create a repository in github with all files needed for composite primary key work in CakePHP 2.x.

**github:** https://github.com/patrickmaciel/cakephp-composite-primary-key

This change allows you to use composite primary in your models, following this instructions:

```
// Add this in your model
public $primaryKey = false;
public $compositePrimaryKey = array('key_one', 'key_two', '........');
```

I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Due the lack of support of composite keys in CakePHP you will have to perform your operations using [Model::query()](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#model-query)

Comment: Is excatly what I'm doing now but, if I use that I can't get the query executed and other informations about the model (data, validation, etc). Or, if I executed a `query` I need do a lot operations manually. Anyway, thanks so much for your time.